# Jc higgins manifold bike

Tags: frames

I have a jc higgins bicycle with manifolds and I want to no if the model number is correct the number is mod 502 307 thanks

Comment: How on earth would we know?

Comment: Do bicycles have manifolds?

Comment: This one does - its one of those "motorbike inspired" designs with a fake petrol tank containing batteries for the lights.  (commenting as well, because answers don't appear for the review queue.)  There is not a lot of info in the question, but its enough to identify the bike.

Comment: Roger - do have a browse through the SE [tour] to see how the site works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you failed to do basic research (ie, use Google).

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, googling "jc higgens bicycle with manifolds" shows that it is a real thing.

[image]

> The bike was sold by Sears in the last couple of months of 1950. The bike was discontinued because of the metal pipes on the tank got in the way of pedalling. The bike had a code number stamped into the frame ***502-307***, denoting this bike was built as a manifold tank bike and not a colour flow. I have talked to a number of bike experts and very few have ever heard or seen one of these bikes. The original colour was red and black.

From http://thecabe.com/forum/threads/j-c-higgins-manifold-tank-bike.13806/

[image]

Opinion: its definitely a cool bike and worth repairing.   If you don't want it, pass it on to someone who can do it justice.

Comment: I didn't realize this wasn't for older bikes  and I thanks you for your help

Comment: @Rogerhoneycutt The main problem is that there was a lack of research done in the first place.  One google search for the Question revealed a number of relevant links, and useful photos.  Still, its a nice bike.

Comment: @Rogerhoneycutt - if this answered your question, you should accept the answer.